# redmine test db load failure

Tags: database, testing, rake, redmine

Just learning to use the redmine test environment.
When I do this:

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate redmine:plugins:migrate redmine:load_default_data RAILS_ENV=test
```

I get a failure:

```
-- drop_table(:open_id_authentication_nonces)
   -> 0.0114s
== 20211213122101 DropOpenIdAuthenticationTables: migrated (0.0194s) ==========

== 20211213122102 RemoveOpenIdSetting: migrating ==============================
== 20211213122102 RemoveOpenIdSetting: migrated (0.0012s) =====================

== 20220224194639 DeleteOrphanedTimeEntryActivities: migrating ================
== 20220224194639 DeleteOrphanedTimeEntryActivities: migrated (0.0088s) =======


Select language: ar, az, bg, bs, ca, cs, da, de, el, en, en-GB, es, es-PA, et, eu, fa, fi, fr, gl, he, hr, hu, id, it, ja, ko, lt, lv, mk, mn, nl, no, pl, pt, pt-BR, ro, ru, sk, sl, sq, sr, sr-YU, sv, th, tr, uk, vi, zh, zh-TW [en] 
====================================    
Error: unknown attribute 'issues_visibility' for Role.
```

I have removed the two plugins I had installed; neither of them had db migrations.

Versions:

```
ruby:    3.0.4p208
redmine: 5.0.1.stable
rails:   6.1.6
```

Answer (score 1):

The `issues_visibility` column is added to the roles table in a migration. However, as the `Role` model class probably still has cached a previous database schema, the assumed schema of the `Role` model might differ from the actual database schema as updated by the migrations.

To fix this, you may want to perform the `redmine:load_default_data` task in a separate rake invocation to make sure that the default data loaded uses the most up-to-date database schema after the migrations.

```
rake db:drop db:create db:migrate redmine:plugins:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
rake redmine:load_default_data RAILS_ENV=test
```

Comment: Thanks.  The first line of your answer is incorrect, as it also contains the load_default_data.  If I leave that out, the two together work.  Please fix the first line; I'll accept the answer then.

Comment: Meh sorry, classic copy&paste error...

Comment: Also note that to run the tests (which bring its own fixtures), you don't need to load the default data at all. If you do not intend to actually tun the tests, you should use a different `RAILS_ENV`, most likely `RAILS_ENV=production`.